# suddenly "my http Apache server stopped working" using xampp

Tags: php, apache

every thing was fine suddenly my server stopped working there is nothing in error logs phpmyadmin is working fine the problem occurs when i am my project first home.php page loaded but when i am sign in entering email id and password server stopped working .
(i have not changed any thing in php.ini)
(earlier it was working fine)

pl
thanks

Comment: Is the Apache service/daemon still running?

Comment: is the apache service still working, are yo sure that the crash is not just coding error that causes a crash in the process, but not the daemon itself? can you still load the homepage?

Comment: If "stopped working" means the apache server crashed, it's not programming related. Be sure to have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your login script. It helps you find out what's wrong with your script, incase that's the problem.

Comment: it does that if you edit the config file and mess with the "htdocs" location sometimes...just a thought..

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, the server stops working after you log in? But phpmyadmin is still working? Something's not right there.

If phpmyadmin is still running after your problem, then the problem is most likely related to your apache config file.

If you cannot access phpmyadmin at all until restart of apache, then you effectively your apache server. However, since nothing is showing up in the error logs, I doubt it somehow.

Could you paste us the relevant parts of your apache config, tell in more detail, what urls you are using to log in, what software you are using (if that is the case, e.g. wordpress) and perhaps generally explain more what you are trying to do?

#### EDIT 1

If it is a PHP related error, try reading the php error log. That log is different from the apache log. Some servers never send error reports to the browser by default and only show a white page. You can find the location of the php log file in your php.ini. Just keep looking for the word `log`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.

I narrowed it down to pages that interfaced with the database seemed to result in this message from Apache.

In my case, Oracle had been upgraded to 11g and caused the OCI connections to fail. No PHP or Apache errors were returned which made it rather difficult to come to this conclusion...

Changing the following in the php.ini (and an apache restart) solved the issue.

```
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
```